# What are the morphisms in the category of retractions?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, monoidal-categories

In Michael Shulman's [Framed bicategories and monoidal fibrations](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/20/18/20-18a.pdf) Example 12.10 he defines a category $\operatorname{Retr}(\mathcal{C})$ as the "category of retractions in $\mathcal{C}$". He gives the objects of this category as pairs of maps $s\colon A\to X$ and $r\colon X\to A$ such that $sr=1_A$ (i.e. $r$ is a retraction with section $s$).

In this example he doesn't tell us explicitly what the morphisms of this category should be. Does anyone know what the morphisms must be to make this example work?

Comment: This is a functor category; it's the category of functors from the "walking retraction" to $C$. So morphisms are natural transformations and you can unroll the definition from there.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What is the walking retraction category? A a few naive google searches don't seem return anything.

Comment: There is a category $R$ such that functors $R\to C$ correspond precisely to retractions in $C$. A morphism of retractions is a natural map. You can work out what $R$ has to be. It has two objects (call them $a$ and $x$) and morphisms $s:a\to x$ and $r:x\to a$ satisfying $r\circ s=1_a$. These generate the category, and there are "no other relations", so that in all there are five morphisms: $1_a,1_x,s,r,s\circ r$. Apparently some people call $R$ the "walking retraction".

Comment: Thanks Tom. This would make the morphisms $(sr\colon A\to X\to A)\to (s'r'\colon B\to Y\to B)$ on $\text{Retr}(\mathcal{C})$ simply pairs of morphisms $f\colon A\to B,\ g\colon X\to Y$ such that the resulting squares commute. I suppose it remains to check that this works for the example of Shulman but I expect it will.

Comment: The "walking" terminology is from nLab, it's a way of referring to the free category on a ___: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/walking+structure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The morphisms can be worked out with the general guideline of category theory that **everything is supposed to be compatible with everything**.

Leaving out the equation $s \circ r = 1$ for the moment, what is the most natural definition of a morphism from $(r : X \to A, s : A \to X)$ to $(r' : X' \to A', s' : A' \to X')$? These should be pairs of morphisms $f : X \to X'$, $g : A \to A'$ which are compatible with $r$ and $s$. And this means $f \circ s = s' \circ g$ and $g \circ r = r' \circ f$.
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>f>> X' \\
@V{r}VV @VV{r'}V \\
A @>g>> A' \\
@V{s}VV @VV{s'}V \\
X @>f>> X'
\end{CD}$$

Actually, this is a special case of a more general construction. Let $\Gamma$ be any graph (in the above example, it has two vertices with two opposite edges between them). The diagram category $\mathrm{Diag}(\Gamma,\mathcal{C})$ consists of $\Gamma$-shaped diagrams. These associate to every vertex $u \in \Gamma$ an object $X_u \in \mathcal{C}$ and to every edge $u \to v$ in $\Gamma$ a morphism $X_u \to X_v$. (No further condition is required.) A morphism of diagrams $X \to Y$ consists of morphisms $X_u \to Y_u$ for all vertices $u$ such that for every edge $u \to v$ the diagram
$$\begin{CD}
X_u @>>> Y_u \\ @VVV @VVV \\X_v @>>> Y_v
\end{CD}$$
commutes. This category is also isomorphic to the functor category $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathrm{Path}(\Gamma),\mathcal{C})$.